# display Category as (ul) item & Subcategory as (li) item in php

Tags: php, treeview

```
function showcategory($parentid)
{
     $sql = "select * from categories where parent_id='".$parentid."'";
     $result = mysqli_query($GLOBALS['conn'],$sql);
     $output ="<ul id ='tree1' >\n";
    while($data=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $output.="<li>\n".$data['name'];
        $output.=showcategory($data['id']);
        $output.="</li>";
    }
    $output.="</ul>";
    return $output;
}
```

I have a treeview created using PHP, and the function that extracts the treeview extracts the category and its subcategory properly. The categories table in the database has a column that holds the specified values (1/0) where 1 is for main categories and 0 is for subcategories. The problem I face is that when I extract the categories from the database, there is no distinction between whether the categories are main or subcategories. They are all displayed as li elements, and I use CSS formatting on the treeview to create a folder icon on the list items. The problem is how to display the main categories that have a value of 1 in the categories table as an ul element that contains a folder icon that can be opened to show what's inside, and the subcategories that have a value of 0 in the categories table should be displayed as li elements without any folder icon (meaning that only the subcategory name is displayed as text).

**my output**
[image]

**I need to get outputs as shown in this image.**
[image]

Comment: Add a class to the `<li>` element to indicate what kind it is, and then use CSS to style it differently?  ie if your 0/1 indicator column is called `type` you could use `$output.= '<li class="type' . $data['type'] . '">'.$data['name'];`

Comment: You could also make the recursion conditional, so `if ($data['type']) { $output.=showcategory($data['id']); }`

Comment: @Rop Eyre How can we ensure checking the value first, whether it is 0 or 1?
where is the part of checking the column value if it is 1 or 2 in your code ?

Comment: "How can we ensure checking the value first, whether it is 0 or 1" - please see my comments and my answer below.  "where is the part of checking the column value if it is 1 or 2 in your code?" you didn't mention values other than 1 or 0 (to indicate a main category or subcategory).  What does a value of 2 represent?  If that's important to your question, please include it in your post.

Comment: @RobEyre Unfortunately, I have not yet been successful in finding the correct solution despite applying all of the suggested solutions in the responses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to query into database only one time other than put DB query in a recursion function.

Take you needs to check where a menu item is main (base on type value 0/1). This add *class='main'* to main item and you can use css to style the main icon. Let's try this modification.

```
function showcategory($data, $parentId = 0) {
$menu = '<ul>';

foreach ($data as $item) {
    if ($item['parent_id'] == $parentId) {
        $menu .= '<li';
        
        // Add 'main' class if 'type' is 1
        if ($item['type'] == 1) {
            $menu .= ' class="main"';
        }

        $menu .= '>';
        $menu .= '<a href="#">' . $item['name'] . '</a>';
        
        // Recursive call to build sub-menu if it has children
        $submenu = showcategory($data, $item['id']);
        if ($submenu) {
            $menu .= $submenu;
        }

        $menu .= '</li>';
    }
}

$menu .= '</ul>';

return $menu;
}

$sql = "select * from categories where parent_id='".$parentid."'";
$result = mysqli_query($GLOBALS['conn'],$sql);
$data=mysqli_fetch_array($result)

$menu = showcategory($data);
echo $menu;
```

Comment: I well try , I think your code is perfect.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have not yet been successful in finding the correct solution despite applying all of the suggested solutions in the responses.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you modify your code so that it takes into consideration whether the item is a main category or subcategory.

*"a column that holds the specified values (1/0) where 1 is for main categories and 0 is for subcategories"* - let's assume this column is called `type`.

```
function showcategory($parentid)
{
    $sql = "select * from categories where parent_id='".$parentid."'";
    $result = mysqli_query($GLOBALS['conn'],$sql);
    $output ="<ul id ='tree1' >\n";
    while($data=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $output.= '<li class="type' . $data['type'] . '">'.$data['name'];
        if ($data['type']) {
            $output.=showcategory($data['id']);
        }
        $output.="</li>";
    }
    $output.="</ul>";
    return $output;
}
```

You should then be able to style the subcategory nodes using CSS, matching on  `li.type0`

Comment: I believe that your code is missing the part that verifies the value of the category in the column first. I think that the verification part is necessary here.